# Loop using Reclassify function: string 'RemapRange' object is not callable

Tags: arcpy, reclassify, for-loop

I am a newbie of python teaching myself using the arcpymanual.
I am running a Reclassify script on slope grids. It works fine for the first loop then I get an error message for the remap line. I cannot figure out what the problem is because I copied the syntax from the arcpy manual. Is it due to loop syntax?

> Runtime error 
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 21, in 
>       TypeError: 'RemapRange' object is not callable

SCRIPT:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\workspace\rsn\pippi"
# Overwrite pre-existing files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Process: Reclassify

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("s_*", "GRID")

for raster in rasters:

    print(raster)

    outRaster =  r"C:\workspace\rsn\pippi\re_" + raster
    print(outRaster)

    RemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 15, 0], [15, 30, 1], [30, 90, 2]])

    outReclassRr = Reclassify(raster, "Value", RemapRange, "DATA")
    print outReclassRr
    outReclassRr.save(outRaster)
```

Can anyone give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable RemapRange is named the same as the object RemapRange which is not good coding practice.  Try renaming that statement to something like:

```
myRemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 15, 0], [15, 30, 1], [30, 90, 2]])
```

I would also recommend to place that statement before the for loop since it is static variable and does not need re-created for each image.

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("s_*", "GRID")
myRemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 15, 0], [15, 30, 1], [30, 90, 2]])
for raster in rasters:
    # continue on with logic
```